# how to have different comments from you in different pages

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I am creating a website that contains different movies, every movie has a specific id_movie, i have added a comment box where the user can add a comment about the movie, however, every movie i click on, they all show the same comments that have been entered, I want every movie to have its own comments, I will be happy if you can help me with that. thanks

comments.php

```
<body>
 <br />
 <h2 align="center"><p >Add Comment</p></h2>
 <br />
 <div class="container">
  <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="5"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
   </div>
  </form>
  <span id="comment_message"></span>
  <br />
  <div id="display_comment"></div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var form_data = $(this).serialize();
 $.ajax({
  url:"add_comment.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:form_data,
  dataType:"JSON",
  success:function(data)
  {
   if(data.error != '')
   {
    $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
    $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
    $('#comment_id').val('0');
    load_comment();
   }
  }
 })
});

load_comment();

function load_comment()
{
 $.ajax({
  url:"fetch_comment.php",
  method:"POST",
  success:function(data)
  {
   $('#display_comment').html(data);
  }
 })
}

$(document).on('click', '.reply', function(){
 var comment_id = $(this).attr("id");
 $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
 $('#comment_name').focus();
});

});
</script>
```

add_comment.php

```
<?php

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_movie', 'root', '');

$error = '';
$comment_name = '';
$comment_content = '';

if(empty($_POST["comment_name"]))
{
 $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Name is required</p>';
}
else
{
 $comment_name = $_POST["comment_name"];
}

if(empty($_POST["comment_content"]))
{
 $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Comment is required</p>';
}
else
{
 $comment_content = $_POST["comment_content"];
}

if($error == '')
{
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO tbl_comment
 (parent_comment_id, comment, comment_sender_name, movie_id)
 VALUES (:parent_comment_id, :comment, :comment_sender_name)
 ";
 $statement = $con->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':parent_comment_id' => $_POST["comment_id"],
   ':comment'    => $comment_content,
   ':comment_sender_name' => $comment_name
  )
 );
 $error = '<label class="text-success">Comment Added</label>';
}

$data = array(
 'error'  => $error
);

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

fetch_comment.php

```
<?php

//fetch_comment.php

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_movie', 'root', '');

$query = "
SELECT * FROM tbl_comment
WHERE parent_comment_id = '0'
ORDER BY comment_id DESC
";
$statement = $con->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = '';
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $output .= '
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">By <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> on <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
  <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
  <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Reply</button></div>
 </div>
 ';
 $output .= get_reply_comment($con, $row["comment_id"]);
}

echo $output;

function get_reply_comment($con, $parent_id = 0, $marginleft = 0)
{
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM tbl_comment WHERE parent_comment_id = '".$parent_id."'
 ";
 $output = '';
 $statement = $con->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $count = $statement->rowCount();
 if($parent_id == 0)
 {
  $marginleft = 0;
 }
 else
 {
  $marginleft = $marginleft + 48;
 }
 if($count > 0)
 {
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
   $output .= '
   <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left:'.$marginleft.'px">
    <div class="panel-heading">By <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> on <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
    <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
    <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Reply</button></div>
   </div>
   ';
   $output .= get_reply_comment($con, $row["comment_id"], $marginleft);
  }
 }
 return $output;
}

?>
```

and here when I click on each movie:

```
<?php include('header.php');
    $qry2=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_movie where movie_id='".$_GET['id']."'");
    $movie=mysqli_fetch_array($qry2);
    ?>
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="content-top">
                <div class="section group">
                    <div class="about span_1_of_2">
                        <h3><?php echo $movie['movie_name']; ?></h3>
                            <div class="about-top">
                                <div class="grid images_3_of_2">

                                    <img src="<?php echo $movie['image']; ?>" width="180px" height="280px" alt=""/>
<?php include('ratte.php'); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="desc span_3_of_2">
                                    <p class="p-link" style="font-size:15px">Type: <?php echo $movie['type']; ?></p>
                                    <p class="p-link" style="font-size:15px">Price: £<?php echo date($movie['price']); ?></p>
                                    <p style="font-size:15px"><?php echo $movie['desc']; ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $movie['video_url']; ?>" target="_blank" class="watch_but">Watch Trailer</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php $s=mysqli_query($con,"select DISTINCT theatre_id from tbl_shows where movie_id='".$movie['movie_id']."'");
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($s))
                            {?>
                            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered text-center">
                            <?php

                                while($shw=mysqli_fetch_array($s))
                                {
                                    $t=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_theatre where id='".$shw['theatre_id']."'");
                                    $theatre=mysqli_fetch_array($t);
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $theatre['name'].", ".$theatre['place'];?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php $tr=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_shows where movie_id='".$movie['movie_id']."' and theatre_id='".$shw['theatre_id']."'");
                                            while($shh=mysqli_fetch_array($tr))
                                            {
                                                $ttm=mysqli_query($con,"select  * from tbl_show_time where st_id='".$shh['st_id']."'");
                                                $ttme=mysqli_fetch_array($ttm);

                                                ?>

                                                <a href="check_login.php?show=<?php echo $shh['s_id'];?>&movie=<?php echo $shh['movie_id'];?>&theatre=<?php echo $shw['theatre_id'];?>"><button class="btn btn-default"><?php echo date('h:i A',strtotime($ttme['start_time']));?></button></a>

                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </table>
                        <div id='display_comment'></div>
                            <?php
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                <h3>No Show Available</h3>
                                <div id='display_comment'></div>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>

                    </div>
                <?php include('related-movies.php');
                ?>
            </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <?php include('comments.php'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: `movie_id` is missing from your INSERT query.

Comment: In your 'AJAX' call to get the comments, `$.ajax({url:"fetch_comment.php",` you need to pass the movie id back to PHP then in the backend you add that id into the SQL to get the comments.  `SELECT * FROM tbl_comment
WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' AND movie_id=?
ORDER BY comment_id DESC`  For the AJAX add `dataType:"json"` then for the `data:` something like `{movie_id : <?php echo $movie_id; ?>}`

Comment: Basically you have to take the movie ID you have when you build the page, and feed that to your call to get comments,  then it dos sort of like a U turn, and goes back to the server where you get the comments.  Oh almost forgot,, using my example above in the function that fetches the commnets, you would use `$_POST['movie_id']` make sure to use prepared SQL statements for security so people cant hack your SQL.  Its dinner right now, but I can post a proper answer in like 30 minutes or so.

Comment: I have tried this thing (AND movie_id=?) but it says this error:PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters in line 15

Comment: I am not that professional in coding and I really dont know what to do, if you have an idea could you please update my code, I would appreciate your help

Comment: Side note: be careful the `add_comment.php` gets abused by careless users / hackers / naughty netizens. They can just keep posting comments non-stop by replaying the POST request, causing DoS or lots of junk data.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try my best, but there is a lot to cover.

**comments.php**

```
//add the target files URL as the form's action
<form method="POST" id="comment_form" action="add_comment.php" > 
 //add movie to the form, that way when we insert the comment we know what its for
 <input type="hidden" name="movie_id" id="movie_id" value="<?php echo $movie_id; ?>" />

//.. in your JS, add the movie id to the fetch comment call
function load_comment()
{
   $.ajax({
      url:"fetch_comment.php",
      method:"POST",
      data: {movie_id : <?php echo $movie_id; ?>},
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(data){
         //...
  })
 }
 //move this below the function definition
 load_comment();
```

---

**add_comment.php**

```
    //add movie id here to match what is in the form above
   INSERT INTO tbl_comment
   (parent_comment_id, comment, comment_sender_name, movie_id)
    VALUES (:parent_comment_id, :comment, :comment_sender_name, :movie_id)
   // add ':movie_id' => $_POST['movie_id'] to the array you have there for
  // $statement->execute([ ....]). The arrays below go the same way 
   //add those to $statement->execute() for there respective DB calls,
```

You had the movie in the FIELDS part of the insert, but not the VALUES, which is probably an SQL syntax error.  You may not have seen an actual error because this is called with AJAX so it would just break on the client side.  You could look in the browser debug window > network [XHR] requests and look at the response.  There you would probably find it or you may simply get a 500 error from the server.

---

**fetch_comment.php**

```
    //add movie id here to match what is in the AJAX fetch comment call
   SELECT * FROM tbl_comment
   WHERE parent_comment_id = :parent_comment_id  AND movie_id = :movie_id 
    ORDER BY comment_id DESC
    //for execute add 
     ['parent_comment_id'=>0, 'movie_id'=>$_POST['movie_id']]
```

***Important*** prepare this query properly

```
   $query = "
 SELECT * FROM tbl_comment WHERE parent_comment_id = '".$parent_id."'
 ";
```

So it should be like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comment WHERE parent_comment_id = :parent_id";
//then add this to execute ['parent_id' => $parent_id]
```

---

**mainpage.php** (not sure the name on this one)

In the last unnamed code chunk you are using `mysqli` but above your using `PDO` it's better to use one or the other, personally I prefer PDO, its just better API wise. You are also not preparing these (so convert these to PDO).  Using both just adds unnecessary complexity to your application (I think there were 2 of theses in there):

```
$qry2=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_movie where movie_id='".$_GET['id']."'");
$movie=mysqli_fetch_array($qry2);
```

It looks like you include the `comments.php` into that last page `<?php include('comments.php'); ?>` So what I would do is where the query is above that I said to fix:

```
   require_once `db.php`; //- create a separate file to do the DB connection for you
  //then you can add that to the top of all the pages you need the DB for

   include 'header.php'; //no need for the ( ) for any of the include* or require* calls.
   /*
   require will issue an error if the included file is not found
   include will fail silently, for things that are required for your 
   page to work and not produce errors use require (like the DB)
   for things you only ever include once, also like the DB stuff use *_once
   then no matter how many *_once calls are stacked from including
   the other page you don't have to worry about it.

    as above those simple rules give us require_once for the DB.
    the other pages I am not sure which would be best.
   */

   //localize the movie ID - change any use of `$_GET['id']
  $movie_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $movie_id : false;

  if(!$movie_id){
      //do something if someone goes to this page with no ?id= in the URL
      //you could redirect the page
      //you could have a default movie id etc...
  } 

  $statement = $con->prepare('select * from tbl_movie where movie_id=:movie_id');
  $statement->execute(['movie_id' => $movie_id]);
  $movie = $statement->fetch();

  //dont forget to fix the other DB call and remove the MySqli stuff.
```

Above I suggest using a single file for the DB, in your case it can be quite simple,

**db.php**

```
    <?php $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_movie', 'root', '');
```

That is literally all you need then, at the very top of each page you use the DB, simply add this file

```
    require_once 'db.php';
```

This way if you need to change the password or something like that, you can go to one place named in way that is easy to remember and change it.  How it is now, you would have to dig though all your code to change it.  In that page your including a file named `header.php` and it looks like from your MySQLi code that it may have some connection stuff in there.  I would remove any MySQLi stuff there too.  You want to keep the DB file separate as you may need to include it in the AJAX backend parts and any output from header.php would mess you up.

**Summery**

What I showed above is a simple example of what you need to do, in that AJAX call This may not be all you need to do, these are just the things that were obvious to me.

You don't have to worry about child comment's movie ID, as they inherit it from the parent comment, which wouldn't exist (on the page) if it had the wrong ID.  In your current setup, I would still save it as part of the data. It's just you dont need it to get child comments if you know the parent (which you sort of have to know).  I didn't add  it into one thing that looked like it was for child comment.  You can add it, but as I said above, it's not really needed.

Really the question is way to broad, why isn't my code working kind of question.  The only reason I took the effort was that you also took the effort to provide well organized code that is relatively minimal.

So thank you for that.

The last suggestion I would make, is clean up the extra line returns in some of the SQL, and format the TABs a bit better.  But that is just a readability issue, I am very picky about formatting my code and some of that could be related to creating an question on SO as it takes a bit of getting used the markdown they use.

Hope it helps you!

**Update**

> thanks for your answer, I really dont know what i should post here and what i shouldnt, and the thing that i dont understand is that: i have a tbl_comment which stores all comments from user and this table include movie_id, and i have another tbl_movie which has movie_id as a primary key, how can i link the movie _id with the tbl_comment so that every comment is stored for a specific movie_id

I will try to explain the flow of your application, with an example.  For the sake of this example lets say the movie id is `12` and our main page is `www.example.com/movies?id=12`:

***Inserting a comment***

1. User goes to a url with `?id=12`

   - everything after the `?` is called the query string
   - PHP knows to take the query string and populate the supper global `$_GET`
   - so in the main page your movie id is now `$_GET['id']`
2. We localize this (make a local variable) at the top of the page with some basic checks. `$movie_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $movie_id : false;`

   - if movie id is set `?id=12` then put it in `$movie_id`
   - if its not `www.example.com/movies` then set `$movie_id` to false
   - this avoids some errors if someone goes to the page without that set
3. At the bottom of the page you include this file `<?php include('comments.php'); ?>` think of it like pasting that code into this place
4. In `comments.php`, which runs when it's included above,

   - if someone inserts a new comment (submits the form) weve added that same `$movie_id` into the form with this line
   - `<input type="hidden" name="movie_id" id="movie_id" value="<?php echo $movie_id; ?>" />`. 
     -So now when the form submits to `add_comment.php` which you need to put in the form's action.
   - `<form method="POST" id="comment_form" action="add_comment.php" >`
   - It will contain the id as `$_POST['movie_id']` on that page. The `$_POST['movie_id']` is basically the same as `$_GET['id']` but the form `method` tells us its `post` instead of `get`.  Typically `Get` is used to retrieve resources, `Post` is used to modify them.
   - When PHP runs the above piece of HTML it replaces the `<?php echo $movie_id; ?>` with it's value of `12` so you get this
   - `<input type="hidden" name="movie_id" id="movie_id" value="12" />`
5. Now On `add_comment.php` (where the form action takes us) we can take that `$_POST['movie_id']` and add that to your SQL used to Insert the comment from the form in #4. into the Database.

   - `INSERT INTO tbl_comment
     (parent_comment_id, comment, comment_sender_name, movie_id)
     VALUES (:parent_comment_id, :comment, :comment_sender_name, :movie_id)`
   - As this is a prepared statement we have the place holder `:movie_id` in the SQL query.  In PDO we can feed that to the PDOStatment object (`$statement`) you get back from `$statment=$conn->prepare($sql)` by calling it's `execute` method or `$statement->execute([..other stuff here..., 'movie_id'=>$_POST['movie_id']])`.
   - The query that runs looks like this after PHP is done with it
   - `INSERT INTO tbl_comment
     (parent_comment_id, comment, comment_sender_name, movie_id)
     VALUES (0, 'foo', 'ArtisticPhoenix', 12)` <-- see what I did there.

So you see we took the value from the original URL request, added it to our form and then we wait for user action to submit that form with the movie id embedded in it.  The when the form submits it calls our add comment page, where we take it out of the Posted data, and feed it into the DB with the rest of the form data for that comment.

The other ones are exactly the same except in those we are using AJAX to submit the data so instead of a form we just add it to the AJAX call.  I will give you an example of how that executes.

***Showing a comment***

This is the same up to #4 above

5. In  `comments.php` you call `load_comment();` "After" defining the function as it doesn't exist tell you do that, so you cant call it before.

   - This runs your AJAX request `$.ajax`, for the purposes of this example think of it like a fancy way to do a form.  The `url` is the form `action` the `method` is well the method.  The `data` is the form data, the `dataType` is the type of encoding in this case `JSON` or Javascript Object Notation.  Which is a fancy way of saying structured data, as in PHP its basically an array (or data with nested elements).
6. The url (`action`) points us to `fetch_comment.php`, so when that runs our `data: {movie_id : <?php echo $movie_id; ?>},` becomes `data: {movie_id : 12},` which gets sent back to server where PHP sees it as `$_POST['movie_id']`

   - Similar to the Insert, we use that ID in our SQL query that pulls the parent comments
   - `SELECT * FROM tbl_comment
     WHERE parent_comment_id = :parent_comment_id  AND movie_id = :movie_id 
     ORDER BY comment_id DESC`
   - This says "Select all columns From table tbl_comment WHERE parent_comment_id  IS 0 and Movie Id is 12"  So it will only return comments for movie 12 that are also parents.
   - in your code you have just `$statement->execute();` But you had the `parent_comment_id` hard coded as `0`.  This was fin until we needed to add the `movie_id` Once we did that it makes more senses to make it part of the prepared statement so it reads better. But like the insert, now we have place holder in place of values so we need to take that data and add it to `execute` for this query.
   - So `$statement->execute();` becomes `$statement->execute(['parent_comment_id'=>0, 'movie_id' => $_POST['movie_id']]);`  Or when PHP is done with it `$statement->execute(['parent_comment_id'=>0, 'movie_id' => 12]);` which the Database knows to use the keys to match the placeholders and it completes our query.
   - `SELECT * FROM tbl_comment
     WHERE parent_comment_id = 0  AND movie_id = 12
     ORDER BY comment_id DESC`
   - Then we take the results and send them back to the `success` handler for the AJAX with `echo` and in this case add it to the page with this line `$('#display_comment').html(data);`

**So In conclusion**

Your code:

```
load_comment();

function load_comment()
{
 $.ajax({
  url:"fetch_comment.php",
  method:"POST",
  success:function(data)
  {
   $('#display_comment').html(data);
  }
 })
}
```

Correct code (what I said):

```
//.. in your JS, add the movie id to the fetch comment call
function load_comment()
{
   $.ajax({
      url:"fetch_comment.php",
      method:"POST",
      data: {movie_id : <?php echo $movie_id; ?>},
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(data){
         //...
  })
 }
 load_comment();
```

What you need to do

```
//$movie_id = $_GET['id'] in the main page that included this file.. #2 above
function load_comment()
{
 $.ajax({
  url:"fetch_comment.php",
  method:"POST",
  data: {movie_id : <?php echo $movie_id; ?>}, 
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(data)
  {
   $('#display_comment').html(data);
  }
 });
}
 load_comment();
```

When PHP completes the above code it sends this to the client (using `12` from our example)

```
//$movie_id = $_GET['id'] in the main page that included this file.. #2 above
function load_comment()
{
 $.ajax({
  url:"fetch_comment.php",
  method:"POST",
  data: {movie_id : 12},  //PHP takes the value of  $movie_id and puts it here
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(data)
  {
   $('#display_comment').html(data);
  }
 });
}
load_comment();
```

Above is what actually runs in the browser

That is pretty much the gist of it.  As I said its more beneficial to you to learn how it works.  Sure I can post the complete code but I have no way to test it, no way to know if that is all the errors or not.  If you learn how it works, you will be better equipped to take on those challenges yourself.  I would rather spend 3 or 4 times the effort teaching you how it all works, then to post some code that you have no idea how it works.

Hope that all makes some sense.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time, i didnt get any error but at the same time all the messages disappeared

Comment: where should i add this? >> ['parent_comment_id'=>0, 'movie_id'=>$_POST['movie_id']]

Comment: The arrays need to go in the `->execute([array])` part just like the INSERT one does.  It seemed long winded to post all the code.  Plus I like to teach, not do.  So its good to leave some things for you to do.

Comment: @beg - its an sql error, but because you call it -via- AJAX the only way you would see it is if you looked at the network panel in `f12` browser debug window.  I added a few things, and prettied it up a bit.

Comment: you are using words where i feel it for professional coder, i am just very new to programing and i am trying to do this comments function, if there is any very simple way i can do so that it could work, please let me know

Comment: as you said you dont like doing but explaining, can you please do it for me and explain it? it is been a while trying to fix this, but here i am

Comment: If you follow what I mention in the answer, it should be pretty easy to figure out even with a basic knowlage of PHP.

Comment: I swear i did, i even read that more than 3 times, but it is still not clear to me, i could tell that you are very expert, and you may see this as an easy thing, but it is really hard for me

Comment: Which part don't you understand.  I am a Cheif Information Officer with over 9 years PHP experience.   But I get what you are saying.  It's just this is not a do my code for me kind of site.  Its a here is the problem I am having and here is my code what did I do wrong.  Even the question really should not have been answerd as it too broad and covers to many topics.  But a lot of people just post stuff like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55133362/errmsgunexpected-exception-try-later-err-code500  So I thought I would be kind as you put some effort into making the question.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I really dont know what i should post here and what i shouldnt, and the thing that i dont understand is that: i have a tbl_comment which stores all comments from user and this table include movie_id, and i have another tbl_movie which has movie_id as a primary key, how can i link the movie _id with the tbl_comment so that every comment is stored for a specific movie_id

Comment: I couldnt make it work, but thanks for you answer, i did get some ideas that i didnt know about before, but for this one idk why it doesnt work, thanks a lot

Comment: As I said quite a few times it's too many questions all at once. If you check for errors such as in the `f12` window, it's better to first search for that error, then if you cant find anyting post each smaller issue as a separate question on SO.  Otherwise we get a huge mess like above that you cant make sense out of.

Comment: If I taught you something beneficial, it was worth my time. I had some HTML classes and basic stuff in college `Associate in webdesign and information systems`  but I learned PHP in the school of hard knocks.  So I know what it's like.  I remember when posting forms finally clicked in my head I was like now it all makes sense.  It took me years to get where I am and I still learn new stuff. Like I just found out the PHP elephant logo was modled off the words PHP ... lol ... who knew.  Currently I probably spend 10 to 12 hours writing code or working on something every day ... lol

Comment: thanks a lot, if you can help me with some stuff that is not working, can i send my work to you via email please? thanks

Comment: No sorry.  I am far to busy for that.  I'm not being rude.  I just have a bunch going on right now at work as I have 3 major projects and we lost our Junior developer a few weeks ago.  Then I have a few projects of my own, just look at the state of my website  http://artisticphoenix.com/  and that is after like 2 years of work lol.  Well I never actually have time to do it.